# Best way to query/display multi-joined data from using Django

Tags: django, django-models

I'm new to Django, a question on query/display of joined tables.

I have a model setup with "managers" and "skills"...and a join table of "managerskills".

ManagerSkills has foreign key links to both the "manager" table and the "skill" table. This is a many to many table. (managers have many skills, skills belong to different managers)

I am looking to retrieve a list of managers, display them in a grid, and have a column for "skills", which would display a comma-separated list of skills associated with the manager.

```
class Manager(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class Skill(models.Model) :
    skill = models.CharField(max_length=15)

class ManagerSkills(models.Model) :
    manager = models.ForeignKey(Manager,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    skill = models.ForeignKey(Skill,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

How would I query this dataset to retrieve distinct list of managers, while also having reference to associated skills that can be output in table/grid?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a many to many relationship, you should declare it as such:

```
class Manager(models.Model):
    skills = models. ManyToManyField("Skill", through="ManagerSkills")
    ...
```

Now in your template you can iterate through `manager.skills.all`.

(Note, if you don't have any other fields on ManagerSkills, you can remove the definition altogether along with the `through` attribute in the field; this makes managing skills in the admin easier.)

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to Django, so didn't apprecaite the "through" attribute...that's nice.